# Rotate kotlin array

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Assume that I have an array like `1 2 3 4 5`, I want to rotate it to the left by **n** and get a new one.

For example the 2 rotation of the above array will result in `3 4 5 1 2`. I didn't found any extension function to do that.

Answer (score 24):

You can use built-in java `Collections.rotate` method, but you need to convert your array to list firstly:

```
val arr = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val list = arr.toList()
Collections.rotate(list, -2)
println(list.toIntArray().joinToString())
```

Outputs

```
3, 4, 5, 1, 2
```

Answer (score 8):

Consider the example:  `1 2 3 4 5` `=>` `3 4 5 1 2`. One approach is:

1. Split the original array into two parts: `1 2 | 3 4 5`
2. Swap the parts: `3 4 5 | 1 2`
3. Combine the parts to get the result:  `3 4 5 1 2`

Here is a sample code (boundary checks omitted, `sliceArray` is an [stdlib function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/slice-array.html)) :

```
fun <T> Array<T>.rotate(n: Int) = 
    sliceArray(n until size) + sliceArray(0 until n)
```

**Example**

```kotlin
arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).rotate(2)
    .also { println(it.joinToString()) } // 3, 4, 5, 1, 2
```

You may want to handle negative rotation and deal with short arrays (those don't really rotate). Here is a more comprehensive code that uses similar approach:

```kotlin
fun <T> Array<T>.rotate(n: Int): Array<T> {
    if (size < 2 || n % size == 0) return this

    val m = when (n > 0) {
        true -> n % size
        false -> ((n % size) + size) % size
    }
    return sliceArray(m until size) + sliceArray(0 until m)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another extension function, by slicing the array in 2 parts `left` and `right` and reassembling it to `right + left`:

```
fun <T> Array<T>.leftShift(d: Int) {
    val n = d % this.size  // just in case
    if (n == 0) return  // no need to shift

    val left = this.copyOfRange(0, n)
    val right = this.copyOfRange(n, this.size)
    System.arraycopy(right, 0, this, 0, right.size)
    System.arraycopy(left, 0, this, right.size, left.size)
}
```

so this:

```
val a = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
a.leftShift(2)
a.forEach { print(" " + it) }
```

will print

```
3 4 5 6 7 1 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple solution:

```kotlin
fun <T> Array<T>.rotateLeft(n: Int) = drop(n) + take(n)
fun <T> Array<T>.rotateRight(n: Int) = takeLast(n) + dropLast(n)
```

The limitation is that `n` must be less than or equal to the length of the array.

Alternatively, you can use `Collections.rotate(...)` as follows.

```kotlin
import java.util.Collections

fun <T> Array<T>.rotate(distance: Int) =
    toList().also { // toList() is a deep copy to avoid changing the original array.
        Collections.rotate(it, distance)
    }

fun main() {
    val xs = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    val ys = xs.rotate(-2)
    xs.forEach { print("$it ") } // 1 2 3 4 5
    println(ys) // [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the record, you can use the regular [`Array` constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/#constructors) to build a new array:

```
inline fun <reified T> Array<T>.rotate(n: Int) = Array(size) { this[(it + n) % size] }
```

The element at index `it` in the source array is copied in the destination array at the new index `(it + n) % size` to perform the rotation.

It is a bit slower than copying the array by chunks.